# How can I scale new data which were not used in training/validating?

Tags: modeling, prediction, scikit-learn, scales

I used [StandardScaler](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html) provided by scikit-learn to scale training and validation data. Then, I fitted a neural network (CNN) model with scaled data for classification. However, in the production stage, I have to predict data in every month in the future (one-by-one). So, I use the scaler which was used in training stage to fit the new data.

My training procedure as follows:

```
sc = new StandardScaler()
sc.fit(train_data)
train_data = sc.transform(train_data)
build model, save(sc)
```

For prediction steps:

```
sc.fit(predict_data)
sc.transform(predict_data)
model.predict(predict_data)
```

There is no information about min/max in my data. I think in the prediction stage, mean and stdev of data will be changed. What should I do in this case to predict new data?

Comment: You should fit it only once on training data. The scaler saves mean and variance that you can later use for transforming new data.

Comment: @hans The future data might have mean value different from training data. Do you have any reference in this case?

Answer (score 1):

You should use the same normalization approach and parameters during the model's training. In your case, you are using [z-score](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_score) normalization which requires two parameters namely mean $\mu$ and standard deviation $\delta$. Thus, you need to store $\mu$ and $\delta$ values in order you can scale out new data during the model's future usage / lifetime.

For example, suppose you have a dataset $D$ to be used in the training of a model $M$ using the [hold-out](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-validation_(statistics)#Holdout_method) schema. Thus, you can do:

$P, V = split(D)$

$\mu = mean(P)$

$\delta = stddev(P)$

$P_z = zscore(P; \mu, \delta)$

$V_z, = zscore(V; \mu, \delta)$

and then you can use $P_z$ to train $M$ and $V_z$ to validate if $M$ will work well on new data.

Now, consider you have new (unseen, unlabelled) data $T$ and want to use $M$ to find (predict) the labels of $T$. Thus,

$T_z = zscore(T; \mu, \delta)$

and then use the model $M$ to predict the labels of $T$ using $T_z$ as input instead of $T$ itself.